# My Android Buttons look a bit weird (screenshot attached)?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNPqN.png)

I want my buttons to be round, but they are oblate/oval (please take a look at the screenshot). Can anyone help? My code (There are 2 buttons at the bottom):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/package_size"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="#e9eaea"/>
    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/small" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/medium" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/large" />
    </RadioGroup>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:background="#e6e7e8"
        >
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_minus"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_plus"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do I need to change Layout? Or why is it happening?

Comment: specify width and height. don't use wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

The plus and minus icons that you are using have a definite height and width. If you place them in a Layout smaller than their default size, they are bound to behave otherwise hence, specify their holder to be of size equal to or greater than the icon size.
In your case, just specify the height of the immediate Linear Layout tag of the buttons.

Comment: I have specified height and width for button tags, and seem to work fine.

Comment: Yes, even that works. Great. Good Luck. @AndreyRuzhencev

Answer (score 0):

You have set the background of button.

Buttons are not square by default so the background is stretched to default width of button.

So set the width and height manually to be same.